# Python (and Django) best import practices

Tags: python, django, python-import

Out of the various ways to import code, are there some ways that are preferable to use, compared to others? This link [http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20200917011425/http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) in short
states that

```
from foo.bar import MyClass
```

is not the preferred way to import MyClass under normal circumstances or unless you know what you are doing. Rather, a better way would like:

```
import foo.bar as foobaralias
```

and then in the code, to access MyClass use

```
foobaralias.MyClass
```

In short, it seems that the above-referenced link is saying it is *usually* better to import everything from a module, rather than just parts of the module.

However, that article I linked is really old.

I've also heard that it is better, at least in the context of Django projects, to instead only import the classes you want to use, rather than the whole module. It has been said that this form helps avoid circular import errors or at least makes the django import system less fragile. It was pointed out that Django's own code seems to prefer "from x import y" over "import x".

Assuming the project I am working on doesn't use any special features of `__init__.py` ... (all of our `__init__.py` files are empty), what import method should I favor, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, it's dependent on the situation. If it's a uniquely named method/class (i.e., not `process()` or something like that), and you're going to use it a *lot*, then save typing and just do `from foo import MyClass`.

If you're importing multiple things from one module, it's probably better to just import the module, and do `module.bar, module.foo, module.baz`, etc., to keep the namespace clean.

You also said

> It has been said that this form helps avoid circular import errors or at least makes the django import system less fragile. It was pointed out that Django's own code seems to prefer "from x import y" over "import x".

I don't see how one way or the other would help prevent circular imports. The reason is that even when you do `from x import y`, ALL of `x` is imported. Only `y` is brought into the current namespace, but the entire module `x` is processed. Try out this example:

In test.py, put the following:

```
def a():
    print "a"

print "hi"

def b():
    print "b"

print "bye"
```

Then in 'runme.py', put:

```
from test import b

b()
```

Then just do `python runme.py`

You'll see the following output:

```
hi
bye
b
```

So everything in test.py was run, even though you only imported `b`

Answer (score 13):

First, and primary, rule of imports: never ever use `from foo import *`.

The article is discussing the issue of cyclical imports, which still exists today in poorly-structured code. I dislike cyclical imports; their presence is a strong sign that some module is doing too much, and needs to be split up. If for whatever reason you need to work with code with cyclical imports which cannot be re-arranged, `import foo` is the only option.

For most cases, there's not much difference between `import foo` and `from foo import MyClass`. I prefer the second, because there's less typing involved, but there's a few reasons why I might use the first:

- The module and class/value have different names. It can be difficult for readers to remember where a particular import is coming from, when the imported value's name is unrelated to the module.

  - Good: `import myapp.utils as utils; utils.frobnicate()`
  - Good: `import myapp.utils as U; U.frobnicate()`
  - Bad: `from myapp.utils import frobnicate`
- You're importing a lot of values from one module. Save your fingers, and reader's eyes.

  - Bad: `from myapp.utils import frobnicate, foo, bar, baz, MyClass, SomeOtherClass, # yada yada`

Comment: A specific exception to this might be in Django where you are importing a class that implements a model (which represents a database table). In that case it's preferred to say "from django.contrib.auth import User". But as I said, this is a convention specific to a particular environment.

Comment: what about `from myapp import utils; utils.frobnicate()`?

Comment: Joschua: that's fine too, since anybody reading through will be able to see where `frobnicate` is being imported from.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of the latter is that the origin of MyClass is more explicit. The former puts MyClass in the current namespace so the code can just use MyClass unqualified. So it's less obvious to someone reading the code where MyClass is defined.