# Django: How to import items from models.py into the views.py

Tags: python, django

I currently have a simple models.py page made

```
from django.db import models


class itemType(models.Model):
    typeName    = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.typeName

class item(models.Model):
    itemName    = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    descip      = models.TextField
    slug        = models.SlugField(max_length = 70)
    itemFront   = models.ImageField( upload_to = "Images")
    itemBack    = models.ImageField( upload_to = "Images")
    pub_date    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now = False)
    itemtype    = models.ForeignKey('itemType')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.itemName
```

And now I am trying to get this information onto my views.py page, but I don't understand how to put transfer it

```
def shop(request):

    context = {

    }
    return render(request,"shop.html" , context)
```

Answer (score 8):

**How to import:**

```
from appname.models import ItemType, Item
```

**PS:** class names should be **[`UpperCamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))** (`Item`, `ItemType`)

**How to use (random example):**

```
def shop(request):

    context = {
        'items': Item.objects.filter(name='xyz'),
        'types': ItemType.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "shop.html", context)
```

---

**Update:**

A more better way is to import the whole module (give it an alias if required) and use as (assuming the above example),

```
from appname import models as appname_models

def shop(request):

context = {
    'items': appname_models.Item.objects.filter(name='xyz'),
    'types': appname_models.ItemType.objects.all()
}
return render(request, "shop.html", context)
```

**PS:** Always try to avoid using `import *` in your code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704156/3418784) for best import practices.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this you can try**.

```
from appname.models import ItemType,Item
             or
from appname.models import *

def shop(request):
    data = Items.objects.all()
    context = {
       'items': data,
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import *
```

**or**

```
from .models import ItemType,Item
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from _appname_.models import *
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.